# spring boot 2 mongo querydsl with kotlin on gradle not generating meta data classes

Tags: mongodb, gradle, kotlin, spring-data, querydsl

I am using Spring boot 2,Mongo db  with Kotlin and query dsl. I am not able to generate metadata classes.
    My build.gradle file  has content

```
 dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
              classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.7"

        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.0.RELEASE'

    }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
compile('com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4')
compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.4"
```

I have entity annotated with @Document. But still Q class is not generated

Is there any other configuration needed to be done.